# R Shiny - Is it possible to make column size interactive depended on input value?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

R Shiny - Is it possible to set interactive column size in UI?

```
fluidRow(
        column( HERE!
```

which depends on input value ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Use `renderUI`:

```
# in server:
output$adaptive_colsize <- renderUI{
     fluidRow(column(width = input$user_input_size, 
                     MORE_UI_STUFF))
    }

# in UI:
uiOutput("adaptive_colsize")
```